# How to change the window size of the kernel in the function Image.glcmTexture in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, texture

I am trying to calculate texture measures in Google Earth Engine. I noticed that in the Image.glcmTexture function, has a variable, kernel, which has a default window size of 3*3. I would like to adjust this window size, but I didn't find information about it, how can this be realized in Google Earth Engine?
[image]

Comment: Actually, the default value for the `kernel` argument is `null`. Did you try using the `size` argument to indicate the size of the neighborhood?

Comment: Yes, I actually changed the size of the neighborhood. But it seems to be different from the size of the moving window (kernel). I tried to define a kernel of another window size and apply it to the function, but the result was different from the texture measure calculated with the same window size in R.

Comment: Ok. I once tried to do the same thing (obtain the same texture values in GEE as the one obtained in R using glcm) and was unable to obtain the exact same values. I even added the conversion of the reflectance values to 64 levels of gray. However, I was unable to track the reason of this difference.

Comment: Can I understand it in this way: the neighborhood size of glcmTexture in Google Earth Engine serves the same purpose as the window size in R, although their results are not the same.

Comment: Yes, that is it.